# Recover Past NSLogs

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, nslog

A tester that uses my application encountered a seemingly un-reproducable bug a few days ago.  I believe the NSLogs that my application records can possibly provide information surrounding the issue, but the Xcode Organizer console only logs the 260 or so previous lines.  Is there some log file located on the device that offers a more extended amount of NSLogs?  The tester has a jailbroken device so accessing the root directory shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Can you get access to their crash or device logs?

Comment: @jsksma2 the device didn't crash on the bug, but I have direct access to their device

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use PList to store the logs?

I have developed some location based apps. I always have to drive around a certain areas to test the accuracy of the **Location Update**, **Region Monitoring** and etc. I store those logs into a PList and I will analyse the logs on the PList after I completed a run.

Example Code:

```
-(void)addLocationToPList{

  NSString *plistName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location.plist"];
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docDir, plistName];

  NSMutableDictionary *savedProfile = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];

  if (!savedProfile){
    savedProfile = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    self.shareModel.myCurrentLocationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  }
  else{
    self.shareModel.myCurrentLocationArray = [savedProfile objectForKey:@"locationArray"];
  }

  if(self.shareModel.myBestLocationDictFromTracker)
  {
      [self.shareModel.myCurrentLocationArray addObject:self.shareModel.myBestLocationDictFromTracker];
      [savedProfile setObject:self.shareModel.myCurrentLocationArray forKey:@"locationArray"];
  }

  if (![savedProfile writeToFile:fullPath atomically:FALSE] ) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't save Location.plist" );
  }
}
```

I call the above function to add the location to a PList whenever there is a location update. You may use it in anyway you want based on what you really need to log.

I think it is much better than the Organizer Console log as you can extract the PList Out and keep a copy on your Mac for future analysis and etc. I am using [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/ifunboxmac/) to access/extract the PList.